# Specify a directive as parameter (plugin) to another directive

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I have a "host" directive, into which I wish to display <del>a "plugin" directive</del> one out of multiple possible "plugin" directives (say, plugin1, plugin2, plugin3 etc), and I want the container of the host directive to specify or change the plugin directive which is to be displayed as a parameter.

Can this be accomplished in angular without the "host" directive knowing anything about <del>it</del> which directive it is displaying?? In a way, it is like the ui-router, where we keep a child view placeholder, and provide the view dynamically. But I want this flexibility  with directives.

For example:

```
<div>
  <host plugin="plugin1 plugin1-param-1 plugin1-param-2"></host>
</div> 
<div>
  <host plugin="plugin2 plugin2-param-1 plugin2-param-2"></host>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply create a `host` component, with a `plugin` directive ? It will behave the same, but this way, I'm pretty sure you can do it

Comment: @trichetriche How do you mean "create a component _with_ a directive"?

Comment: Well, you create a component `ng g g myComponent`, then a directive `ng g d myDirective`, and in your directive selector, you say it only works with your component, and do what you want in it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come from the Java / .Net background, so I was looking to apply a runtime  "plug and play" pattern. I think transclusion is the answer to my question above. Here's a helpful link:
[http://teropa.info/blog/2015/06/09/transclusion.html](https://teropa.info/blog/2015/06/09/transclusion.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can inject the host directive into the plugin directive.

For easier configuration, you can name the input exactly the same as the directive's attributive name.

```
@Directive({selector: '[plugin]'})
class Plugin {
  @Input('plugin') config: any
  constructor(@Host() private host: HostCmp) {}
}
```

You now have access to `HostCmp` instance via `this.host` and the configuration will be in `this.config`

You can further scope down the usage of plugin only to a particular host based on the selector by using `host[plugin]` as the selector.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I think my question was confusing, so I have updated the question. Per my understanding, the response you have provided will link one plugin to my host directive. But I want to decide which plugin to use in the host directive only at runtime.

Comment: Wrong approach. Angular is statically analyzing your code. You should create a single directive which can be configured using some input parameters if you want to determine its behavior at runtime.